# DD-WRT PPTP Enabled

Tags: vpn, dd-wrt, pptp

My DD-WRT router is behind ISP Router

DD-WRT Firmware: DD-WRT v3.0-r29114 std (02/17/16)

ISP Router 192.168.1.1
DD-WRT Router 192.168.1.2

Enabled PPTP on DD-WRT as shown below

[image]

Besides this do i need to open any particular ports on my ISP Router and forward those ports to DD-WRT Router

Regards

Comment: please do share the reasoning behind -1, I am just happy to have an answer but would be nice to know what i did wrong :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, port 1736 (common PPTP port) and you'll also have to ensure you're forwarding/allowing the GRE protocol (protocol 47, not port 47) through as well.  Depending on your ISP-provided router, this may not be an option.

Another option is to put the DD-WRT into the ISP router's DMZ; again, if it supports it.

Comment: My ISP router is cable model, it's ARRIS, i do see "Enable PPTP Pass Through" which is enabled

Comment: PPTP Passthrough is not the same as allowing GRE in. PPTP passthrough is for multiple clients to be able to use PPTP from behind the NAT router (ie, you PPTP'ing to another server outside your network, not the other way around).  Forwarding PPTP and GRE inward to a server on the LAN probably isn't going to happen with a consumer-level NAT device (with stock firmware anyway).

Comment: I think you are right I tried adding 1736 to my Arris and got an error "Table FWVirtSrvTable is full"

Comment: Not sure what's up with that, but for PPTP/GRE/Passthru and NAT info, check this out: http://www.think-like-a-computer.com/2011/07/28/pptp-passthrough/

Comment: thank you for the help you pointed me in right direction, I am going to play around with these settings and will share what works